# Syntax error when using count in loop

Tags: count, stata, stata-macros

I am trying to run a loop where I count the total in each file under the variable `_merge`, and then count certain outcomes of `_merge`, such as `_merge=1` and so on. I then want to calculate percentages by dividing each instance of `_merge` by the total under `_merge`.

Below is my code:

```
/*define local list*/
local ward_names B C D E FN FS GS HE


/*loop for each dbase*/
foreach file of local ward_names  {
use "../../../cleaning/sra/output/`file'_ward_CTS_Merged.dta", clear

count if _merge
local ward_count=r(N)

count if _merge==1
local count_master=r(N)

count if _merge==2
local count_using=r(N)

count if _merge==3
local count_match=r(N)

clear 
set obs 1 

g ward_count='ward_count'
g count_master=`count_master'
g count_using=`count_using'
g count_match=`count_match'
g ward= "`file'"

save "../temp/`file'_collapsed_diagnostics.dta", replace

clear
```

The code was running fine until I tried to add the total count for each ward file:

```
g ward_count='ward_count'
'ward_count' invalid name
```

Is this a syntax error or something more severe?

Comment: `tab _merge` will give you percents. No need to write your own code counting instances, putting counts in new variables. starting a new dataset. Also, it's a fair guess that you would be better off `append`ing datasets for different wards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use ` instead of ' when you refer to a local macro:

```
generate ward_count = `ward_count'
```

**EDIT:**

As per @NickCox's recommendation you can improve your code by using the `tabulate` command with its `matcell()` option to get the counts all at once:

```
tabulate _merge, matcell(A)

                 _merge |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------------------+-----------------------------------
        master only (1) |          1       16.67       16.67
            matched (3) |          5       83.33      100.00
------------------------+-----------------------------------
                  Total |          6      100.00

matrix list A

A[2,1]
    c1
r1   1
r2   5
```

So you could then do the following:

```
generate count_master = A[1,1]
generate count_match = A[2,1]
```

Comment: Afterwards `mat pc = 100 * A / _N` takes a vector of counts and produces one of percentages.